How to save a numpy array in .fvecs
I'm using faiss to create an index out of vector embeddings, which can then be used for performing similarity search. Since my dataset runs into billions, I'm looking for extremely fast (near-optimal) solutions. I saw that faiss has a good support for cases where the entire dataset need not be loaded into memory for indexing. However, all of the code demos and examples (benchmark scripts) use .fvecs files, which I believe is a great way since they can be mmapped (by numpy). I'm unsure though, how could I store the embeddings returned as torch tensors into .fvecs format?
I have the current implementation to save vecs as a .fvecs file:
def write_fvec(filename, vecs):
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        nvecs, dim = vecs.shape
        f.write(struct.pack('<i', nvecs))
        f.write(struct.pack('<i', dim))
        vecs.astype('float32').flatten().tofile(f)

a = np.random.rand((1000000, 1024))
write_fvec("test_file.fvecs", a)

But when I use this to read using faiss' code that uses the given function to read it,
def mmap_fvecs(fname):
    x = np.memmap(fname, dtype='int32', mode='r')
    d = x[0]
    return x.view('float32').reshape(-1, d + 1)[:, 1:]


I get the following error:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1024000002 into shape (1000001)

I'm using an array of dimensions 1000000x1024
